# How to avoid links to map.root getting shortened?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Reports controller and various reports:

```
http://localhost/reports/main/this_month
http://localhost/reports/main/last_month
http://localhost/reports/main/this_year
```

I wanted http://localhost to default to http://localhost/reports/main/this_month. That is easy enough using map.root in my routes.rb.

However when I do this any links to http://localhost/reports/main/this_month are now shortened to just http://localhost. I want the links to stay full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is very possible in Rails 2. The url string that is generated depends on which url helper you call in your view.

```
map.reports '/reports/:action/:timeframe', :controller => :reports
# todo pretty this up with some more named routes for reports
map.root :controller => "reports", :action => "main", :timeframe => "this_month"
```

Now, `root_url` will be `http://locahost/`. When you use `reports_url(:action => 'main', :timeframe => 'this_month')`, it will be `http://localhost/reports/main/this_month`. They both render the same action.

It sounds like you have set up the root, but just don't create any links with `root_url`.

Comment: Yes, map.reports and using reports_url does the trick. I don't really understand why reports_url doesn't shorten but the following does: <%= link_to_unless_current 'This Month', :controller => 'reports', :action => 'main', :timeframe => 'this_month' %>

Comment: More problems: using a named route for reports now means that if I use <%= link_to_unless_current 'This Month', reports_url(:action => 'main', :timeframe => 'this_month') %> to disable the current page in the menu, this code does not treat http://locahost/ as current.

Comment: Favor the `_path` named routes over their `_url` counterparts on site pages.`link_to_unless_current` uses the current url to see if there is a match - you may want to override it in `application_helpers.rb` to handle your special case.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using a dummy controller that makes a `redirect_to`.

Routes:

```
map.reports '/reports/:action/:timeframe', :controller => :reports

# this triggers the action 'index' on 'welcome'
map.root :controller => "welcome"
```

And then on the Welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < Application: ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to :controller => "reports", :action => "main", :timeframe => "this_month"
  end
end
```

Comment: That works, but it's a redirect. So the user no longer sees `/` in the url bar. And it's a 2nd request - totally unnecessary.

Comment: I see. I thought he wanted "not to see" the / .

Comment: As Jonathan points out, I don't mind seeing / in the browser's url bar, it is the links in my app where I don't want to see /

Comment: However I now getting problems with link_to_unless_current so I might actually just go for a redirect for now.

Comment: Well, I'm glad I could help. As a side note, I've investigated and redirects don't generate a second request on the browser, so the performance penalty shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible in Rails 2 by default. There is a plugin called [Redirect Routing](http://github.com/larspind/redirect_routing) that will allow it, however, which you could look into. In Rails 3, this functionality is built in. You can read about it in [The Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) over at Engine Yard.

Comment: If you put the monthly_reporting route above the root route it will match that first.